# Article/post drafts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a wiki application in Rails that would be publicly editable. I have an articles controller and a drafts controller. When someone clicks 'edit' on an article, I would like to create a new draft with the contents of the original article, and then save that to the database table when the user clicks 'save'. Any ideas on how I might go about doing this? I've been stuck on it for a few days.

Currently, each article belongs_to a category, a subcategory, and has_many drafts.

Database schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160723153357) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "subcategory_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "drafts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "subcategory_id"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  create_table "subcategories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

end
```

Articles_controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    if params[:category].blank? && params[:subcategory].blank?
      @articles = Article.all.order("created_at DESC")
    elsif params[:subcategory].blank?
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
      @articles = Article.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @subcategory_id = Subcategory.find_by(name: params[:subcategory]).id
      @articles = Article.where(subcategory_id: @subcategory_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    @parameters = article_params
    @parameters[:category] = Category.find_by(id: Subcategory.find_by(id: article_params[:subcategory_id]).category_id)
    @article = Article.new(@parameters)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title,:content,:subcategory_id)
    end
end
```

Drafts_controller:

```
class DraftsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_draft, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /drafts
  # GET /drafts.json
  def index
    @drafts = Draft.all
  end

  # GET /drafts/1
  # GET /drafts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /drafts/new
  def new
    @draft = Draft.new
  end

  # GET /drafts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /drafts
  # POST /drafts.json
  def create
    @parameters = draft_params
    @parameters[:article_id] = params[:article_id]
    @parameters[:subcategory_id] = 2
    @parameters[:category_id] = 2
    @draft = Draft.new(@parameters)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @draft.save
        format.html { redirect_to @draft, notice: 'Draft was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @draft }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @draft.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /drafts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /drafts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @draft.update(draft_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @draft, notice: 'Draft was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @draft }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @draft.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /drafts/1
  # DELETE /drafts/1.json
  def destroy
    @draft.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to drafts_url, notice: 'Draft was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_draft
      @draft = Draft.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def draft_params
      params.require(:draft).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

Article model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :subcategory
  has_many :drafts
end
```

Draft model:

```
class Draft < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :subcategory
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Comment: please post some controller/view code?

Comment: Might as well throw in article.rb and draft.rb too.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You have article_id. Just load the article and there you have title/content to be copied to a new draft.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am relatively new to Rails...could you please explain how I would do that?

Comment: Alright, I eventually solved it by passing the `article_id` parameter through the form using a hidden field, which allowed me to use `params[:article_id`] in the `drafts_controller.rb`. This went off what @SergioTulentsev suggested. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, I thought you're already passing article_id correctly. Hence my suggestion. :)

Comment: No, I was a little confused since I didn't really understand how parameter passing worked all that well, but I think I've pretty much got it now. The whole drafts thing works without any issues :)

Answer (score 0):

I think an approach I would probably follow would be to extract the content information to another table altogether. Here's a rough implementation I could come up with immediately:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  #column_names: ['type:string']
  has_many :contents
  has_one :current_content, -> { current.or(approved) }, class_name: 'Content'
  delegate :title, :content, to: :current_content, allow_nil: true
end

class Content < ApplicationRecord
  #column_names: ["article_id:int", "title:string", "content:text", "status:int"]
  belongs_to :article
  enum status: [:unapproved, :approved, :current]
end

class Draft < Article
  #use STI here
end

#services/set_current_article_content.rb
class SetCurrentArticleContent
  attr_reader :article, :content
  def initialize(article, content)
    @article = article
    @content = content
  end

  def call
    article.current_content.approved!
    content.current!
  end
end

#services/edit_wiki_content.rb
class EditWikiContent.rb
  attr_reader :article, :content
  def initialize(article, content)
    @article = article
    @content = content
  end

  def call
    article.contents << content
    content.save!
  end
end

#services/publish_draft.rb
class PublishDraft
  attr_reader :draft
  def initialize(draft)
    @draft = draft
  end

  def call
    draft.becomes!(Article)
  end
end
```

There are three services which would handle the updating and setting of the current content and also publishing the draft, you could add some additional logic in any of them. Also note the condition for the current_content in the article model, your logic might be different from the way I have implemented it.